# make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop. C/C++ Problem

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I am trying to compile a code that I downloaded from GitHub https://github.com/severinson/VLC-driver on Eclipse CDT 3.8.1  and getting this error:
`"make: *** No rule to make target 'x86_64all'"`.
I have included all linux-headers (linux-headers 4.15.0-58 generic) and I have searched a lot for this error and everyone is saying to make changes to the makefile. I am unable to find the makefile and how can I make changes to a makefile?

```
    ################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: VLC_Driver

# Tool invocations
VLC_Driver: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Linker'
    gcc  -o "VLC_Driver" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(EXECUTABLES)$(OBJS)$(C_DEPS) VLC_Driver
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Comment: Can you show us your makefile ?

Comment: @cocool97, I have added a makefile that is generated when I compiled my code. How can I make changes to this makefile?

Answer (score 1):

In your Makefile, where you see labels like this:

```
VLC_Driver: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
```

VLC_Driver here is a target.  The default target in <s>a standard make command</s> this make command is `all`.  For whatever reason, Eclipse is targeting `x86_64all` which you do not have.  To edit the build target in eclipse go to the Make Target view:

Window > Show View > Make Target

You are going to want to set it to `all`.

More information [here](https://brlcad.org/wiki/Compiling/Eclipse/Manually).

Comment: The default target for `make` is not `all`, it is the first regular target (that does not start with `.`) in the Makefile, which happens to be `all` in this case (and in many other Makefiles). Maybe Eclipse uses a different convention, adding to potential confusion.

Comment: @chqrlie TIL.  I've been using Makefiles for years and didn't know that.  Then, I suppose the root of the issue may actually be the Makefile generation.  Either way, my answer should work.